# changes made in my variables.scss isn't working on subsequent clones of my repo

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I've been adding styling to my variables.scss.  It works on my MAC, but when another developer checks out the code they're not seeing the styling that's in the variables.scss.

```css
  .md body {
    --ion-background-color: #ffffff;
    --ion-background-color-rgb: 18, 18, 18;

    --ion-text-color: #ffffff;
    --ion-text-color-rgb: 255, 255, 255;

    --ion-border-color: #222222;

    --ion-color-step-50: #1e1e1e;
    --ion-color-step-100: #2a2a2a;
    --ion-color-step-150: #363636;
    --ion-color-step-200: #414141;
    --ion-color-step-250: #4d4d4d;
    --ion-color-step-300: #595959;
    --ion-color-step-350: #656565;
    --ion-color-step-400: #717171;
    --ion-color-step-450: #7d7d7d;
    --ion-color-step-500: #898989;
    --ion-color-step-550: #949494;
    --ion-color-step-600: #a0a0a0;
    --ion-color-step-650: #acacac;
    --ion-color-step-700: #b8b8b8;
    --ion-color-step-750: #c4c4c4;
    --ion-color-step-800: #d0d0d0;
    --ion-color-step-850: #dbdbdb;
    --ion-color-step-900: #e7e7e7;
    --ion-color-step-950: #f3f3f3;

    --ion-item-background: #1e1e1e;

    --ion-toolbar-background: #4854e0;

    --ion-tab-bar-background: #4854e0;

    --ion-card-background: white;

    ion-icon {
      color: white;
    }

    ion-label {
      color: white;
    }

    ion-title {
      text-align: center;
    }

    .profileBg {
      background-image: url("../assets/background-images/headerBg.png") !important;
      padding-top: 1px !important;

      img {
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        border-radius: 25%;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 60px auto;
        display: block;
      }
    }

    .alert-radio-label.sc-ion-alert-md {
      padding-left: 52px;
      padding-right: 26px;
      padding-top: 13px;
      padding-bottom: 13px;
      -ms-flex: 1;
      flex: 1;
      color: #222428;
      font-size: 16px;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .authui {
      --background: white;
      --color: black;
    }

    .alert-sub-title.sc-ion-alert-md {
      color: black;
    }

    .alert-message.sc-ion-alert-md {
      color: black;
    }

    .submit {
      --background: #4854e0;
      color: white;
    }

    .action-sheet-icon.sc-ion-action-sheet-md {
      padding-bottom: 4px;
      margin-left: 0;
      margin-right: 32px;
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      font-size: 24px;
      color: black;
    }

    .action-sheet-button-inner.sc-ion-action-sheet-md {
      color: black;
    }

    .standardBackground {
      --background: #fff url("../../../assets/background-images/login-image.jpeg") no-repeat center center / cover;
      padding-bottom: 55px;
    }
  }
```

Any idea why this is happening? Why is the styling in variables.scss only working on my mac and when other devs checkout my code the styling in variables.scss isn't working?

Any help would be greatly appeciated.

Comment: How are others checking out your code? Is it on a server or are they putting copies of your files onto their own machines? How is SCSS being set up?

Comment: cloning from gitHub.

I just have it in my theme/variable.scss file

Comment: How do you compile scss?

Comment: I don't.  I'm just running in local host